# "Too [adj] to [verb]" structure

Tags: grammar

What is the correct grammatical structure for to say "too [adj] to [verb]"?
For example, "this is too sweet to eat" or "It's too bright outside to sleep".
Would it be something like 「甘いすぎるから、食べる事ができない」？But I feel this translates more to "because it's too sweet, I can't it eat". I'm looking for a more natural way to say this that would resemble the English "too [adj] to [verb]".
Anyone can help? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Be careful about trying to make translations closer to English. It often is not possible, and when it is, it is often actually making it sound less natural for native speakers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*this is too sweet to eat*

> 甘すぎて、食べられない

*It's too bright outside to sleep*

> 明るすぎて、眠れない

The ~sugite is not always necessary.

> 明るくて、眠れない

I'm using the potential form of the verb here. You can use ことができない to replace it if you're uncomfortable with it, but the long form sounds stiff to me.

Comment: Is the "~すぎて" ever required?

Comment: @Blavius Not required, but it helps provide context. I find a plain 甘くて食べられない quite odd on its own without further context.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Japanese native speaker.
Your sentence, "甘いすぎるから、食べる事ができない" is a little strange. Correct one is "甘すぎるから、食べる事ができない". Japanese words change irregularly influenced by back word. There are 6 types of verb conjugation. I guess it's a little complex for non-native speakers, haha.
Anyway, I guess  you want to emphasize "甘い" don't you?
Then your sentence already includes the expression for emphasis, "すぎる".

Or you feel another problem for your expression?
At least when I learned English, I heard, "When we translate "too [adj] to [verb]" into Japanese, we should use the structure, "[adj] because..."."
So it's alright to use it, I think.